# Having trouble with Django Url Capture

Tags: python, django, url, request, response

I am using Django as backend to capture the following url :

http://localhost:8000/api/v1/cabs/ola/redirect#access_token=703d3830760f40e88a74a9f1d5c053

If I do return `HttpResponse(request.get_full_path())` it shows me `/api/v1/cabs/ola/redirect`

But I want to capture the part after the '#' in `string/list/dict` i.e `access_token=703d3830760f40e88a74a9f1d5c053`

I am currently using Django 1.9.1

Comment: Server will ignore everithing after `#`

Comment: The browser will not even send anything after `#`. Did you mean to use `?`, to send the access token as a `GET` parameter?

Comment: Well I have solved the problem using a html page and javascript in intermediate stage to capture the parameters after #. And then I am sending it to the backend